# echo -n not working under cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I want to echo something to a file, for example:

```
aaaa
bbbb
```

`man echo` says:

```
-n     do not output the trailing newline
```

So I `echo -n aaaa\r\nbbbb > somefile.txt`

but the `\r\n` is output as text, not newline...
The command above is ok under ubuntu12.04.
I'm using win7 64bit, cygwin 1.7.16-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo -n aaaa$'\r\n'bbbb > somefile.txt
```

That works under cygwin and ubuntu.

Edit:

or

```
echo -e 'aaaa\r\nbbbbb' > somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes and the `-e` option to enable interpretation of backslash escapes:

```
echo -en "aaaa\r\nbbbb" > somefile.txt
```

*Tested in Cygwin, Does the job :)*